# Delegating OnUpdate... messages from CMainFrame in MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am using MFC and have a main frame and this receives the WM_PASTE, WM_COPY messages etc from the toolbar.
What I want to do is pass this message on to the CPaneDialog which has the focus, because this is where I want my pasted text to go.

I've figured out how to send the message to the correct view, by using this:

```
void CMainFrame::OnEditPaste()
{
  GetFocus()->SendMessage(WM_PASTE, 0);
}
```

What I want to do now is ask the form if it can receive a paste message.  I figure I can do this by passing on the command ui message...but how do I do this?

```
void CMainFrame::OnUpdateEditPaste(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
  if(GetFocus())
  {
    GetFocus()->???
  }
}
```

If there's a better way to do this then please let me know that as well.

I have tried

```
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_EDIT_PASTE, &CDerivedPaneDialog::OnUpdateEditPaste)
```

in my derived CPaneDialog but this does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MFC uses *command routing* to get commands (and UI updates) to the code that can handle them.  If you fix the routing, this should handle both the paste command and the UI update for it.

This article describes [the default routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/shfzay75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

This article describes [how to change the routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ytfexb5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Basically, you override [`OnCmdMsg`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k63bsef7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in your frame and call the `OnCmdMsg` in your pane to see if it wants to handle the message.  If it doesn't then call the base class to do the standard handling.

Comment: Upvote for posting links, getting it right and working *with* MFC instead of against it.

Comment: This now works great!  I am trying my best to work with MFC...I think there's a decent framework buried in there somewhere.